# Slow website after some time (with ajax interval of 10 seconds)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, response

I have created a Hotel Management System which is loaded with scripts especially ajax.

The main interface comprises of checked in guests which is being updated/refreshed every 10 seconds.

The reason for that is to inform the user (cashier) that a guest's stay is over.

The problem is, when I have 80 or more rows (checkin), the system slows down. It's consuming a lot of memory.

My resolution was to upgrade the RAM to 6GB and increase the cache size of google chrome to 200MB.

Unfortunately, the problem still exists.

I appreciate your help and time. Thank you.

One more thing, one solution was to restart the computer and it comes back to normal. However, after some time, it will come back. The system is running 24/7 and being restarted every 12 hours.

Here's an image of the user interface.
http://s12.postimg.org/qoc6t75q5/Capture.png

Comment: first thing, you shouldn't use an interval but use a timeout and recall it once the previous request has completed. But should just give a better behaviour, i don't think it will really fix your issue.

Comment: Indeed, is your issue server side or client side? I guess client side, so you could still after some time automatically refresh/reload page on client, this should avoid any memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Here's an update. The call is this:
setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10000);

My friend tells me of socket issues. But I don't think I understand his point.

The workstation is where the system is located. So basically, it's all in a single computer. Hope it helps

Comment: So you are already using a timeout, good point but you should avoid using `arguments.callee`. Provide more of relevant code regarding your logic of ajax request. Maybe someone will see what could be your issue. EDIT: so client and server is the same computer?

Comment: Yes. We're in the testing phase of the system and the owner insists on using the same computer. Although our suggestion was to store the server someplace else then we could make use of a LAN. Trying to replace arguments.callee.

Comment: I tried giving the function a name, like getContents(), and replaced argument.callee to getContents() and got an error.
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: It should be: `setTimeout(getContents, 10000);`, not `setTimeout(getContents(), 10000);`, right?! Even it would look like bringing gun to pillow fight, you could consider to use websockets

Comment: oh silly me. Now I put the timeout below (document).ready, and to test it, I made it 1 second timeout. And it doesn't seem to call the function since the timers are not moving every second.

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's quite impossible to see what's going wrong. And, of course, you should set a cache system/logic server side. Server should return complete datas only if there is some change in DB.

Comment: I see. Here's a link to the complete code uploaded in dropbox. I hope you don't mind.

Here's what I did:
After page loads, I call getContents(), then at the end of the function, setTimeout(function(){getContents},5000) is called. 
Problem is, it doesn't load the page again. 
File:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/azi51w0pzp69kgh/checkin.php
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Is is `setTimeout(function(){getContents();},5000)` or `setTimeout(getContents,5000)` but not: `setTimeout(function(){getContents},5000)`. BTW, you need to set this code in complete callback of ajax request. It doesn't seem like you have implement any cache logic server side. You don't need for example to refresh data on UI if  request returns exact same datas as the previous request. Like i said, you have to implement some logic server side to not request database if not needed on each ajax call.

Comment: I will be working on your suggestion that won't require a lookup to database if there's no change at all. Thanks for that.

However, your question, if I use setTimeout(getContents,5000), it returns an error. Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: "if I use setTimeout(getContents,5000), it returns an error. Maximum call stack size exceeded" It shouldn't, just like here: http://jsfiddle.net/xLWRT/  It will if you use: `setTimeout(getContents(),5000)`

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I based it from that code and I came up with something like this:

`getContents();`
`function getContents() {`
`...`
`setTimeout(getContents,5000);`
`}`. It's working fine now. Thank you. I may need to write a logic to avoid getting data if it's not needed. I'll post some updates after a day or two. Thank you.